# How to change header title of new page in orangehrm

Tags: php, symfony-1.4, orangehrm

I have created a menu and a page using data from a database.
But my problem is that I want to change the page header title. I am unable to find the page where to change it.

See screenshot below. I have mark the title that I need to change. Some content also needs to be changed.

[image: orangehrm image]

Answer (score 0):

Check the table `ohrm_menu_item`. The title is there at `menu_title` column.

Answer (score 0):

Navigate to `..\symfony\plugins\orangehrmAdminPlugin\modules\admin\templates\`
open the the corresponding php file and change the header title from there.